# при пинге пингуется другой ip

Tags: маршрутизация, ping, mikrotik

Добрый день, есть комп в сети с внешним ip. При пинге с пк(за микротиком) пинга нет, непосредственно с микротика ответ идет с адреса городской сети. Физически нахожусь в одной сети этого же провайдера.

`ping 80.xxx.xxx.xxx
num/host/time/reply size/ttl
0 10.xxx.xxx.xxx 0ms 50 63
1 10.xxx.xxx.xxx 0ms 50 63`

Вопрос, почему так и как заставить пинговаться адрес с локальной машины.

Comment: Вопрос очень сложен для понимания. Наспишите пожалуйста что конкретно вы пингуете, расстановку сети, и так далее - подробнее.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает что вам надо копать в сторону arp proxy, либо сужать маску подсети на компах с реальниками, либо прописывать маршрутизацию вручную, если реальник пингуемой машины попадает под маску рельника пингующей. Да, схема сети не помешала бы ...

Comment: DNS -  и обратные зоны

Comment: выполните команду `tracert необходимый_ip` и прикрепите вывод этой программы к ответу. и объясните что такое микротик.

Comment: Пингую реальник, который дает провайдер. пинг из сети провайдера, но грубо говоря из другого конца города. предположим реальник 1.1.1.1 локальные адреса 10.100.0.0/24. Трассировка до хоста выглядит как: router->unreacheble->ipшник. Могу предположить, что реальник дается через NAT. Микротик - роутер. DNS мне кажется тут вообще ни при чем... я же не доменное имя пингую...